# Angular Azure Active Directory B2C Authentication - CORS issue

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

I am implementing Azure Active Directory B2C authentication in Angular. I am using msal interceptor to connect Azure AD B2C. The authentication request fails with error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/...'
>   from origin 'http://localhost/...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

[image: browser console screenshot]

I configured everything according to this post: https://medium.com/@sambowenhughes/configuring-your-angular-6-application-to-use-microsoft-b2c-authentication-99a9ff1403b3

Comment: Im not familiar with your technologies, but ive encountered CORS error (php + react), what it is actually saying is that you need to have present response header "access-control-allow-origin" with correct value (or wildcard ).  Maybe as a quick dirty fix (obviously not for production only for dev) try using some cors browser extension ?

Comment: @matri70boss The error is coming from Azure AD B2C in this case, for which we cannot control CORS headers. The URL seems to be correct format though, it seems a bit odd that CORS is being blocked by B2C in this case :\

Comment: @juunas yes your right. While run "signin" policy from "Userflow" it is redirecting to http://localhost:4200/ and I am getting token but while running from an angular application I am getting cors issue. Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue or I have to make any configuration changes in Azure AD B2C tenant to enable cors from my origin

Comment: Is it a GET request or some other HTTP Method? We only support GET to that endpoint. Some libraries try to do OPTIONS, which fails.

Comment: It is a Get request to that endpoint. The library I am using in angular is MSAL

Comment: @juunas i get that it isnt your API / you cant control (add) response headers easily, but i think its highly likely that there is some option / setting that adds those headers

Comment: I have one solution that we have to take one custom page and deploy it in Azure WebApp and enable cors by this cors will work and redirect to http://localhost:4299

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT any answer on this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using the b2clogin.com and latest msal version?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same CORS error using the `knownAuthorities: ['myapp.b2clogin.com']` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article is about two years old and `this.clientApplication.authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/"` doesn't look right. It should be something like `https://${b2cTenantName}.b2clogin.com/${b2cTenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Sign_In`.

Can you try to configure the angular sample app from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular-spa and use that as a starting point?